# Prove functions $e^{ikx}$ are orthonormal on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show the following identity $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(k-k')x}dx = \delta(k-k'),$$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac function. In the text it says that the functions $u_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}$ represent an orthonormal system and in order to show this it provides the identity above. In case $k=k'$ the right and left hand side of the equation coincide, i.e. $\delta(k') = \infty.$ The quetsion is then why $u_k$ would be orthonormal. In case $k \neq k'$ I do not know how the left hand side will vanish. Can somebody provide a comment or an explanation of how to check that $u_k$ is orthonormal and why there are the difficulties I raised above ?

Many thanks.

Comment: In which space(s) are you working? $\delta(k-k^\prime)$ is not a real map.

Comment: No, those functions are not orthonormal on $\Bbb R$. Whatever book this is, don't believe what you read there unless you know the proof

Comment: What is the title of the book? And who is the author?

Comment: One would need to define the symbol $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx}\,dx$ to show that it is equivalent to the Dirac Delta distribution $\delta(k)$.  I've posted an answer that provides this definition.

Comment: What was meant is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-1/\epsilon}^{1/\epsilon}e^{i(k-k')x}dx=\eta_\epsilon(k-k')$ for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$, with $\eta_\epsilon$ a nascent delta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to assign a meaning to the symbol $\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(k-k')x}\,dx$.

Suppose $\psi\in \mathbb{S}$ (i.e. $\psi$ is a Schwartz function). Then, we define the distribution denoted by the symbol $\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(k-k')x}\,dx$ in terms of the following:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{L\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(k') \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-L}^L e^{i(k-k')x}\,dx\,dk'&=\lim_{L\to\infty} \frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(k') \frac{\sin(k-k')L}{k-k'}\,dk'\tag1
\end{align}$$

I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038581/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-sinnx-pi-x-is-a-delta-function/4038638#4038638) that the limit on the right hand side of $(1)$ is equal to $\psi(k)$.  Therefore, we find that in distribution

$$\lim_{L\to\infty}  \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-L}^L e^{i(k-k')x}\,dx=\delta(k-k')$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: Right. Of course that does not show that the functions $e^{ikt}$ are orthonormal...

Comment: Why the book (quantum mechanics) says the functions are orthonormal ? It is in the context of Fourier transformation.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Indeed it does not show orthonormailty on the reals.  And as you pointed out, it should not.  ;-))

Comment: @user996159 I have not read the book to which you refer.  But yes, if we interpret the symbol of interest as a Fourier transform, and let $f_{k'}(x)=\frac1{2\pi}e^{-ik'x}$, then, we have 

$$\langle \phi,\mathscr{F}\{f_{k'}\}\rangle=\langle \mathscr{F}\{\phi\},f_{k'}\rangle=\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\}=\phi(k')\implies \mathscr{F}\{f_{k'}\}=\delta(k-k')$$

Answer (score 1):

What you say the book says is simply nonsense; none of the integrals even exist.

The functions are *not* "orthornomal on $\Bbb R$"; they don't have a chance to be since they're not square-integrable. Of course they are sort of analogous to orthonormal in some sense. Heh, they *are* orthonormal on the Bohr compactification...