# Proving that the Fourier transform of the identity is the Dirac delta using test functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta, schwartz-space

For every finite Schwartz function $f$ and every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, define the Dirac delta as

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt f(t) \delta(t-t') := f(t').$$

How do I proof with this definition that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega e^{i\omega(t-t')} =2\pi \delta(t-t'). $$
When I use complex analysis, this gives me zero for all $t, t'$ since there are no poles and the contour, which clearly is wrong.

I would like to know this way of a proof to understand what the following integral is in distribution sense:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty d\omega e^{i\omega(t-t')} |\omega|^{a}, $$
with real $a > 0$.

Comment: See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943) in which I developed the Fourier Transform for $|x|^\alpha$ for all real $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Hi,@MarkViola, I have been going throught the answer you suggested above, is there some more reading material on the $D_2$ distribution that you use in that answer. And I'm also a bit stuck on why the second contribution in equation 8 disappears. I was not sure if this was the place to ask but I didn't know of any other way. (Amazing answer btw.)

Comment: For the distribution $D_2$, it is a generalization o the $\lambda_r$ functional that Terry Tao defines in Exercise 13 on [THIS PAGE](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/).  I'm not sure what is meant by the "second contribution in equation 8" of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943)

Comment: And feel free to up vote any answer that  you find useful.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I meant how did the second equality in (8) hold.  But I think I found now how it worked, combining the two exponentials gives $e^{in\pi} = 1$ and using $\sin(sign(k)a)=sign(k)\sin(a)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $t'$ for each $A$ let
$$g_A(t)=\int_{-A}^A  e^{i\omega(t-t')}d\omega = 2 \frac{\sin(A(t-t'))}{t-t'}$$
Then $\lim_{A\to \infty} g_A$ converges to $2\pi \delta(.-t')$ in the sense of tempered distributions.

To see this let $$h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t \frac{2\sin(u)}{u}du$$
For any $\phi \in S(\Bbb{R})$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t) g_A(t)dt = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(t+t') h(At)dt$$
$h(At)$ converges to $2\pi 1_{t >0}$ in $L^1_{loc}$ and uniformly away from $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ so $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi'(t) h(At)dt$ converges to

$$-\int_{t'}^\infty 2\pi\phi'(t)= \phi(t')$$

Note that this is the proof of the Fourier inversion theorem at least for the Schwartz functions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(t)=e^{-i\omega t'}$ and $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$.  Then we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}^{-1}\{f\},\phi\rangle&=\langle f,\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t'} \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\,d\omega\\\\
&=\phi(t')
\end{align}$$

where the last equality is a consequence of the Fourier Inversion Theorem (See Appendix).  Therefore, in distribution we have

$$\mathscr{F}^{-1}\{f\}(t)=\delta(t-t')$$

---

**APPENDIX:  PROOF OF THE INVERSION THEOREM FOR SCHWARTZ FUNCTIONS**

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814073/fourier-representation-of-diracs-delta-function/3818103#3818103), [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038581/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-sinnx-pi-x-is-a-delta-function/4038638#4038638) and in the Alternative Development section of [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152426/definite-integral-for-exp-i-ax/4152554#4152554), I proved that $\frac{\sin(Lt)}{\pi t}$ is a nascent Dirac Delta.  Using this result, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t'} \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\,d\omega&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t+t')e^{i\omega t}\,dt\,d\omega\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t+t') \int_{-L}^L e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\,dt\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t+t') \frac{2\sin(Lt)}{\pi t}\,dt\\\\
&= \phi(t')
\end{align}$$