# Fourier transform of a generalized function of $e^{ix}$

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I want to solve $\mathscr{F}\{e^{ix}\}(\xi)$ in terms of distributions.

This is what I did

$$\mathscr{F}\big(e^{ix}\big)(\xi) = \int  e^{ix} e^{i(\xi,x)}\text{d}x$$

But how do I get further from here?. I used the formula in Vladimirov,  on p 108, but this seems to me too general as a solution.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where did $\phi$ come from? It's not in the left-most part.

Comment: That is the formula . It is a  distribution, so $\phi$ is a rapidly decreasing test-function.

Comment: It should also be in the first part, the one that now is $\mathscr{F}\big(e^{ix}\big)(\xi).$ You are confusing the definition of ordinary functions with the one for distributions. The first part should be $\langle \mathscr{F}\big(e^{ix}\big), \phi \rangle.$

Comment: but this is taken from the book

Comment: Really? If so, it's hopefully a mistake by the author and noted in the errata.

Comment: @md2perpe It is written on p 108, at the first equation of section 6.2 $$\mathscr{F}[f(x)](\xi)=\int f(x)e^{i(\xi,x)}dx$$ . If you insert  $e^{ix}$ you get what I wrote. Note the comma in the exponent of the Fourier transform function.

Comment: That formula is correct. It's the definition of the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function $f.$ But in your post you don't have that right hand side; instead you have an extra integral involving $\phi.$

Comment: Hei Per, I edited the question, so it is more in accord with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{ix}$ and let $\phi\in \mathbb{S}$.  Appealing to the Fourier Inversion Theorem, we have $$\begin{align}
\langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi\rangle&=\langle f,\mathscr{F}\{\phi\},\rangle\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ix}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\xi)e^{i\xi x}\,d\xi \,dx\\\\
&=2\pi \phi(-1)
\end{align}$$

Hence, in distribution $e^{ix}=\delta(x+1)$.

Comment: Thanks Mark, how did you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  In going from the second to the third (last) line, we invoked the inversion theorem.

Comment: does this mean one doesn't do double integration like in multivariable calculus?

Comment: The double integral has a value equal to $2\pi \phi(-1)$

Comment: By reading on the Fourier Inversion theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem, I can't understand how you got that from WIki. Can you show this perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article uses a slightly different version of the Fourier Transform.  Note that there is a $2\pi$ factor in the exponentials.  See [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4595078/proving-that-the-fourier-transform-of-the-identity-is-the-dirac-delta-using-test/4595438#4595438) for a proof.

Comment: Thanks Mark, as usual, great help and patience (which is not often found here), but also a big thanks to Per!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz You're welcome.  It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit confusing with the variables in the definition of the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution. We are used to having $x$ or $t$ as variable for the plain function, and $\xi$ or $\omega$ for the transformed function, but of course we can have any variable. Below I will use $y$ for the transformed function. Hopefully it helps you see what is going on.

Let $u$ be a tempered distribution. Its Fourier transform $\hat u$ is defined by
$
\langle \hat{u}, \varphi \rangle
= \langle u, \hat\varphi \rangle
$
for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}.$

Abusing integral notation this means
$$
\int \left( \int u(x) e^{-ixy} \, dx \right) \varphi(y) \, dy
= \int u(x) \left( \int e^{-ixy} \varphi(y) \, dy \right) dx
.
$$

For $u(x) = e^{ix}$ this becomes
$$
\langle \mathcal{F}\{e^{ix}\}, \varphi \rangle
= \int \mathcal{F}\{e^{ix}\}(y) \, \varphi(y) \, dy
= \int \left( \int e^{ix} e^{-ixy} \, dx \right) \varphi(y) \, dy
\\
= \int e^{ix} \left( \int e^{-ixy} \varphi(y) \, dy \right) \, dx
= \int e^{ix} \mathcal{F}\{\varphi\}(x) \, dx
.
$$

Comment: Yes, I have that formula too, on the same page of Vladimirov. But you could also not get any further?  This  is actualy what I wrote at first.

Comment: @Luthier415Hz After this last step, apply the inversion theorem to arrive at the result $2\pi \phi(-1)$.  Then, deduce the FT of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Inversion theorem? Do you have Vladimirov book? I havent  seen it in it.

Comment: Thanks Per!! That was very helpful.